Vue3/Nuxt3 virtual view for table content which support both horizontal and vertical scroll
In Vue3/Nuxt3, I need a library that supports virtual view for grids (similar to react-virtualized MultiGrid in React) that can handle both horizontal and vertical scrolling for table content.
I haven't had success with some of the libraries I've tried so far like vue-virtual-scroller, vue-virtual-scroll-grid, vue-virtual-collection from antv/select as the performance is not optimal when dealing with large amounts of data.
I tried implementing it myself, but it's not as straightforward, and scrolling is not as smooth as without virtualization. Even when using it with antv/select, there's still lag.
So I'm seeking guidance from the experts:
Are there any recommended libraries that support this use case well?
Or any tips on how to mitigate the lag issues when using virtual view and scrolling?
I looked into surely, but adding it to Nuxt3 caused some issues with loading CSS from Less, and it's also a paid solution which makes it less desirable.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any clarification or have additional details to add.
This is my sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-v6uj6z
Are there any recommended libraries that support this use case well?
Or any tips on how to mitigate the lag issues when using virtual view and scrolling?

Give a try to this page: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue Should find one there maybe.
